# How to add cell colour to non-numeric values in R ? (formattable or DT)

Tags: r, dt, formattable

got the following data

```
library(formattable)
DF <- data.frame(Ticker=c("", "", "", "IBM", "AAPL", "MSFT"),
    Name=c("Dow Jones", "S&P 500", "Technology", 
       "IBM", "Apple", "Microsoft"),
         Value=(c(15988.08, 1880.33, NA, 
            130.00, 97.05, 50.99)),
              Change=(c(-0.0239, -0.0216, 0.021, 
               -0.0219, -0.0248, -0.0399)))
```

trying to visualize it in a table like in formattable or in DT

only problem is that i want to add different cell colours for each of the Name values

so basically when you look at the table you are looking at the name which is a coloured cell

can't seem to do it in DT or formmattable

any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to color all row or only the Name cell?

Comment: color only the cell name - not the entire row

Comment: any ideas how to do cell only?

Comment: Does it have to be with `DT` or `formattable`? have you considered `tableHTML`? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/conditional_column.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want ? I don't know what's the issue with the cell containing "`&`"...

```
DF <- data.frame(Ticker=c("", "", "", "IBM", "AAPL", "MSFT"),
                 Name=c("Dow Jones", "S&P 500", "Technology", 
                        "IBM", "Apple", "Microsoft"),
                 Value=(c(15988.08, 1880.33, NA, 
                          130.00, 97.05, 50.99)),
                 Change=(c(-0.0239, -0.0216, 0.021, 
                           -0.0219, -0.0248, -0.0399)))

colors <- substring(viridisLite::viridis(nrow(DF)), 1, 7)

datatable(DF) %>%
  formatStyle(2, backgroundColor = styleEqual(DF$Name, colors))
```

[image]

---

## EDIT

One has to escape the column to solve the issue:

```
datatable(DF, escape = 2) %>%
  formatStyle(2, backgroundColor = styleEqual(DF$Name, colors))
```

[image]